# echo in an href line doesn't works

Tags: php, html, wordpress, echo

Hello I'm trying to edit a wp-plugin, I think that what I want to do It's very simple, but for some reason It doesn't works, I check the code and read a lot of posts on internet and I can't see anything wrong, this is the code.

```
<?php
global $before_title, $after_title, $current_user; 
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
?>...
...{ echo '<li><a href="/wp-admin/profile.php">'.__('Profile', 'sb-login').'</a></li>'; }
```

All I want to do is change the `href="/wp-admin/profile.php"` by `href="/foros/usuarios/<?php echo $current_user->user_login; ?>"` like in other part of the code that says:

```
<a style="color:#0176AB;" title="Go to your wall" href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/author/<?php echo $current_user->user_login; ?>"><?php echo $current_user->display_name; ?></a>
```

but it does'nt works the link that I get is always "the same code" I mean:

`href="/foros/usuarios/<?php echo $current_user->user_login; ?>"` and I get literally [`"mysite url"/foros/usuarios/<?php echo $current_user->user_login; ?>`]

I don't know what is wrong I also try just putting

```
href="/foros/usuarios/$current_user"
```

I tried a lot of other things also, but I can´t see what is wrong. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the above snippet. I believe you been called the php tag inside php. I am not sure did you notice that?

Plugin snippet

```
<?php
    global $before_title, $after_title, $current_user; 
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    ?>...
    ...{ echo '<li><a href="/wp-admin/profile.php">'.__('Profile', 'sb-login').'</a></li>'; }
```

Your Snippet as per you mentioned in the above.

```
<?php
    global $before_title, $after_title, $current_user; 
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    ?>...
    ...{ echo '<li><a href="/foros/usuarios/<?php echo $current_user->user_login; ?>">'.__('Profile', 'sb-login').'</a></li>'; }
```

In your snippet this code is wrong. It should be look like this way

Corrected Snippet

```
<?php
    global $before_title, $after_title, $current_user; 
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    echo '<li><a href="/foros/usuarios/"'.$current_user->user_login.'>'.__('Profile', 'sb-login').'</a></li>';
```

I hope it may help

Comment: With your Correct Snippet i got "[My Site]/foros/usuarios/" the part of ['.$current_user->user_login.'] don't appears.

Comment: not sure the echo statement which is in php ? can you place full function of code instead of ...?

Comment: I rewrite a little bit and it works the solution was:
`<a href="/foros/usuarios/'.$current_user->user_login.'">`

Comment: Thanks to all of you, I'm very new with all this code stuff, I really didn't know anything about coding, I just infer what I could do according what I could read in the same code, sometimes I get it sometimes I don't.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo '<a style="color:#0176AB;" title="Go to your wall" href="'.get_site_url().'/author/'.$current_user->user_login.'">'.$current_user->display_name.'</a> ';`?>
```

Comment: I am not able to write whole line.

Comment: echo '<a style="color:#0176AB;" title="Go to your wall"href="'.get_site_url().'/author/'.$current_user->user_login.'">'.$current_user->display_name.'</a> ';

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your code snippets, but it looks like you're using `<?php echo("..."); ?>` within a `<?php` tag .. like so:

```
<?php
  ...
  <?php echo "..." ?>
  ...
?>
```

The solution is simply to try the inner `<?php echo "..." ?>` by itself (outside the external php block).